# Debugging a C++ code

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, return, operator-overloading

I am not able to understand what is being returned from function in following code (**pointer or value**) .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class safearay
{
    int a[10];
public:
    int& operator [](int n)
    {
        if(n<0 || n>5 )
        {
            cout<<"Exceeded bounds"<<endl;
        }
        return a[n];
    }
};
int main()
{
    safearay sa1;
    for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        sa1[j]=j*j;
    }
    for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        int u=sa1[j];
        cout<<u<<endl;
    }
}
```

Please explain

Comment: it returns a reference to the nth element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention that in your code you do this:

```
 safearay sa1;
sa1[j]=j*j;
```

Normally you cannot access the object values like  this. The method you're asking about is the operator overload method, that defines what whould the object do on such an access.

```
int& operator [](int n)
    {
        if(n<0 || n>5 )
        {
            cout<<"Exceeded bounds"<<endl<<;
        }
        return a[n];
    }
```

means

> return the reference to the value in the n'th place of the array a in object `safearay` if n is in
>   range
>   The return value is passed by reference, therefore you can assign to it and the change will be in `a[i]`

You can read more about operator overload [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

More about passing values by reference [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)

Comment: if it returns value then how assignment is happening ?

Comment: It returns reference to the value, means you can change it, note `int&`. It's C++, you have one more option  - by reference, not only by pointer and by value

Answer (score 1):

```
int& operator [](int n)
```

returns a reference to an `int`.
Essentially, you can use it as `int`, but changes will affect `a[n]` in the class too (because it's returned). It's like a pointer without all the `*`, except you can't change the address where it points to.

Comment: Does the following statement makes sense ::  A function that returns a reference , is treated as if it were a variable . It returns alias to a variable, namely the variable in the function's return statement . So it can be used on the left side of an assignment operator .

Comment: `A function that returns a reference , is treated as if it were a variable.` Not the function itself is treated as variable, but what it returns. Else, everything is true.